# Why wso2 server doesnot work from wso2 user?

Tags: linux, wso2

When I am trying to run server from the instance, its says :
"./wso2server.sh: 189: kill: Operation not permitted."
Now every time when I have to start or stop the server ,i have to move to root and do that.. I have checked the permissions for the server instance folder ,they have the permissions for that particular user only.

Can you tell me what is the issue,So that I can start/stop server from that particular user only ?

Comment: AFAIK, there should be no issues when running a WSO2 Product as a normal user. What is the product you are trying and what is your Operating System?

Comment: For wso2 gateway Esb,Dss and As product I cannot start/stop the server from that particular instance.I need to switch to root in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you start the server as root user then that process is not permitted to kill by another user. This is not specific to WSO2 server.

Comment: Yes ,I believe that may be somewhere we have started the server from the root user and permissions have been changed there only for root user, So can you specify the file in wso2 instance whose permissions may be effected , If so I can simply change the permissions there.

Comment: When you start the server as normal user what response you get? Check the permission of the start up script.

Comment: It shows operation not permitted,and i have checked the permissions,the permissions are given to that particular user only not to the root.